# Android - How to detect that SIP/Voip communication is occurring.

Tags: java, android, events, sip, voip

I'm trying to write a listener that can tell me how long I've been talking over Voip. Since SIP seams to be the most popular I've focussed on that so far. I have an application that runs as a background service to do this detection.

Is there any way to detect that SIP/Voip communication has occurred from other applications?  In the case of SIP, everything I've seen so far requires me to have knowledge of the SIP Profile. My application is completely standalone. I don't need to do anything with it other than just detecting that a Voip call has started and ended.

Because of this, I've thought about checking to see if the microphone and headphone are active at the same time, and then using [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) to see if the application is sending and receiving data.  But so far I haven't been able to get this working either.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to do this? Sample code is very appreciated.

Cheers!